# How to invert a digital signal from operational amplifier

Tags: digital-logic, inverter, function-generator, operational-amplifier

I have built myself a simple square wave generator with an operational amplifier and it works grea, but I want a second one with an inverted output.

Are there high voltage Logic OR gates ? [image: square wave gen]

Comment: You haven't shown your supply voltages. Is it a symmetrical supply? e.g., +/- 12 V?

Comment: There are lots of HV logic gates called half  and full-bridges. But your logic of using an Op Amp without specs, is premature.

Comment: WHat does "How to invert a digital signal from operational amplifier" have to do with "Are there high voltage Logic OR gates ?" ?

Comment: Your over-complicating the wheel. Just add an op-amp inverter to the output of this one. Buy a dual op-amp and have both in the same 8 pin package...lol!

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5Igb6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If it's a symmetrical supply (rather than single-ended) then just add an inverting stage after Vout on your circuit. The gain is given by \$ -\frac{R2}{R1} \$ which works out at -1 in this example.

Comment: The supply voltage is +15 and - 15V and on the output i have a square wave with an amplitude of 13V peak to peak. I dont know how to invert such a high voltage  ,  im asuming to use transistors to make a crood OR gate

Comment: @Simeon, with respect to GND, what is the highest and lowest voltage of the output? You say it is 13V peak-to-peak, but you don't say what the high and low levels are, and this is important.

Comment: @Simeon: Use an op-amp as suggested in my answer.

Comment: https://www.circuitlab.com/editor/#?id=9x9x4rnz8224  sorry forgot to mention there is a capacitor on the non inverting input 1u

Comment: Only registered users can see that link. If you are asking a question about a different circuit than the schematic you have posted then you are wasting everyone's time. Please fix your question. There's a CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar that adds an editable schematic into your question. Show supply rails and all component values and part numbers where appropriate.